# how to add JPanels on JPanels while changing the background and making them visible

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jpanel, graphics2d

I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe game with A.I in java, but I'm new to Swing and graphics with Java. First off, I can't change the background color of my JPanel even when I set Opaque `true`(see class `ttt` below). I was however able to change the background of the JFrame (see class `tttFrame`). Secondly, when I try to add JPanels (these panels are where the X and O's will go) to the top of my current JPanel - the one with the lines (or maybe it does, but the background color of the JPanels don't change) they won't show. The `testpanel` and the panels in `tttGrid` both don't show up. I'm assuming I got the wrong idea of how to implement JFrames and JPanels.

My code also throws a nullpointerexception at `this.add(tttGrid[r][c]);`. `tttGrid` is basically a 2D array of JPanels that are intended to display X or O when clicked by the user/computer. I'm not sure how my code leads to the nullpointerexception. I did some testing as you'd notice on the lines before `this.add(tttGrid[r][c]);`, I get this output on the console window:

```
actual label, row 0 col 0
actual label, row 0 col 1
actual label, row 0 col 2
null label, row 1 col 0
null label, row 1 col 1
null label, row 1 col 2
null label, row 2 col 0
null label, row 2 col 1
null label, row 2 col 2
```

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ttt extends JPanel{
    
    private char playerChoice;
    private JPanel[][] tttGrid;

    public ttt(){
        
        //this.setOpaque(true);             Why isn't setBackground working in JPanel and 
        //this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);   only working in JFrame class?
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        this.setFocusable(true);

        tttGrid = new JPanel[3][3];
        for(int y = 50; y <= 290; y+=120){
            int r = 0;
            int c = 0;
            for(int x = 70; x <= 310; x+=120){
                tttGrid[r][c] = new JPanel();   
                tttGrid[r][c].setBounds(x,y,120,120);
                tttGrid[r][c].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                tttGrid[r][c].setOpaque(true);
                c++;
            }
            r++;
        }
        
        for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++){
            for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++){
                if(tttGrid[r][c] == null){
                    System.out.println("null panel, row " + r + " col " + c);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("real panel, row " + r + " col " + c);
                }
                this.add(tttGrid[r][c]); //nullpointerexception
            }
        }
        
        //testing if JPanel is visible 
        JPanel testpanel = new JPanel();
        testpanel.setBounds(70,50,120,120);
        testpanel.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        testpanel.setOpaque(true);
        this.add(testpanel);
        
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(new Color(153, 250, 255));
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
        g2d.drawLine(70, 170, 430, 170);
        g2d.drawLine(70, 290, 430, 290);
        g2d.drawLine(190, 50, 190, 410);
        g2d.drawLine(310, 50, 310, 410);
    }

    public void gameStart(){

    }

    public void drawXO(){

    }

}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class tttFrame extends JFrame{
    
    public tttFrame(){

        this.getContentPane().add(new ttt());
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Tic-Tac-Toe");
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("ttt.png");
        this.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
        this.setBackground(new Color(0,225,237)); //Background color only works on JFrame
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new tttFrame();
  }
}
```

The photo below is what I get when I comment out the code `this.add(tttGrid[r][c]);`

[image: output when code is run]

Comment: Your NPE is caused by the reseting of `r` in the first `for-loop`

Comment: You next problem is, you're fighting the layout management and paint systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, several compounding issues.

First, your NPE is been caused by the fact you are resetting the `r` value on each iteration of your compounded `for-loop`s

```
for (int y = 50; y <= 290; y += 120) {
    int r = 0;
    int c = 0;
    for (int x = 70; x <= 310; x += 120) {
        tttGrid[r][c] = new JPanel();
        tttGrid[r][c].setBounds(x, y, 120, 120);
        tttGrid[r][c].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        tttGrid[r][c].setOpaque(true);
        c++;
    }
    r++;
}
```

In this case, `r` is ALWAYS `0`

Next, you're fighting the layout manager of the panel.  A `JPanel` by default makes use of a `FlowLayout`.  Setting the `bounds` of a component in this case will have no effect and the `FlowLayout` manager will attempt to make use of the components `preferredSize` to determine how best it should be laid out.

This would have produced an undesirable result for you, expect ...

Next, you're fighting the paint subsystem.

By overriding `paint` you are taking over complete control of how the component, and its children, are painted.  If you don't want that much control, you should first call `super.paint` to ensure that the paint chain is maintained.

However, as a general rule, you should really consider overriding `paintComponent` instead (just don't forget to call `super.paintComponent` first)

Take a look at:

- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html)

for more details.

## Runnable example

The following example makes use of `GridBagLayout`.  This is a some what more complicated layout manager and you could get a similar result using a `GridLayout`, but I like the flexibility that `GridBagLayout` offers me.

[image: Simple example]

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new tttFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    public class tttFrame extends JFrame {

        public tttFrame() {
            this.getContentPane().add(new ttt());
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setTitle("Tic-Tac-Toe");
//            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("ttt.png");
//            this.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
            this.setBackground(new Color(0, 225, 237)); //Background color only works on JFrame
//            this.setResizable(false);
            this.pack();
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public class ttt extends JPanel {

        private char playerChoice;
        private JPanel[][] tttGrid;

        public ttt() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            tttGrid = new JPanel[3][3];

            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                    CellPanel panel = new CellPanel();
                    add(panel, gbc);
                    tttGrid[row][col] = panel;
                    gbc.gridx += 1;
                }
                gbc.gridy += 1;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setColor(new Color(153, 250, 255));
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));

            int cellSize = 120 + 10;
            int boardSize = cellSize * 3;

            int x = (getWidth() / 2) - (cellSize / 2);
            int y = (getHeight() / 2) - (boardSize / 2);

            g2d.drawLine(x, y, x, y + boardSize);
            x += cellSize;
            g2d.drawLine(x, y, x, y + boardSize);

            x = (getWidth() - boardSize) / 2;
            y = (getHeight() / 2) - (cellSize / 2);
            g2d.drawLine(x, y, x + boardSize, y);
            y += cellSize;
            g2d.drawLine(x, y, x + boardSize, y);
        }

        public void gameStart() {

        }

        public void drawXO() {

        }

    }

    // You don't "need" to do this, but it ensures that each instance
    // is always the same
    public class CellPanel extends JPanel {

        public CellPanel() {
            setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(120, 120);
        }

    }
}
```

One thing that this example does do, is demonstrates how flexible a layout manager can be, for example, the window is now re-sizable

[image: Resizable]

You could, with minimal effort, have the cells fill ALL of the available space as the window is resized, but, that's up to you

Comment: So will `setBounds()` work with other layout managers like `BorderLayout`?

Comment: @SpaceMonk No - layout managers take over the control of positioning and sizing the child components, that's their job - I'd strongly encourage you to learn how to work with them, and which ones to use depending what you want to achieve